# How can I get single column from multiple columns?

Tags: mybatis

I have a query look like this.

```xml
<select id="select..." resulType="???">
    SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS count,
        NAME AS name
    FROM
        ...
    GROUP BY
        ...
    ORDER BY
        count ASC
</select>
```

I actually need to fetch those `name`s as ordered and I want my mapper interface be looked like this.

```java
/**
 * Lists names ordered by ... count.
 * ...
 */
List<String> select...(...);
```

How can I do this? What type of `resultType` is required?
Do I need a specified `resultMap`?

Comment: What does your return list look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just mention `resultType="string"`.

For example, I tried the below query:

```
<select id="getCountriesSortedByLanguages" resultType="string">

    SELECT c.name, count(cl.language)
    FROM country c
    JOIN countrylanguage cl ON cl.countrycode = c.code
    GROUP BY c.code
    ORDER BY 2 DESC 
</select>
```

And my mapper is defined as:

```
public List<String> getCountriesSortedByLanguages();
```